# Github actions looking for package.json in a nested folder

Tags: jestjs, yaml, github-actions

Github action searches for package.json in the project, but in a folder with the same name as the project (`'/home/runner/work/javascript-coding-challenges/javascript-coding-challenges/package.json'`). I don't have `package.json` there.

My `jest.yaml`

```
name: Run Jest tests
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Install modules
      run: npm install
    - name: Run tests
      uses: stefanoeb/jest-action@1.0.3
      with:
        jestArgs: passWithNoTests
```

Error:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/javascript-coding-challenges/javascript-coding-challenges/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/javascript-coding-challenges/javascript-coding-challenges/package.json'
npm WARN javascript-coding-challenges No description
npm WARN javascript-coding-challenges No repository field.
npm WARN javascript-coding-challenges No README data
npm WARN javascript-coding-challenges No license field.
```

I am not entirely sure how to remedy this. Is it possible to "exit" from the current folder? (like `cd ..`) This will allow github action to find the correct folder where package.json is located.

I've checked these two answers:

[github actions can not find package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613938/github-actions-can-not-find-package-json)

[npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Nuwanst\package.json'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531633/npm-warn-enoent-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-open-c-users-nuwanst-packag)

but both of them are not answering my question (I see in first one changing `uses` into `./` but I want to use this specific action)

Comment: `/home/runner/work/javascript-coding-challenges` is where your workflow runs.  The `javascript-coding-challenges` below that is where the repository was checked out.  So if your repo has a `package.json` checked in, it should indeed be at `/home/runner/work/javascript-coding-challenges/javascript-coding-challenges/package.json`.  Why do you think it's a level up?  If you run `ls -l` as the first step of your workflow, what do you see?

Comment: @EdwardThomson, I can't even... I solved it. It was so 'stupid and obvious at once' because my package.json went missing and I was 120% sure it was in this PR. But that taught me - actions are looking for a nested 'project name' if there is no package.json and it was not commented on in other problems I found